# RSpec, JavaScript event test do not match

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am working on a rails project and i have a test like below

slim file

```
a href="#" title="メールアドレスのルール説明" id="my_balloon"
```

js file

```
$(function() {
  var shown = false;
  $('#my_balloon')
    .showBalloon()
    .hideBalloon() //一旦非表示
    .on("click", function(){
       shown ? $(this).hideBalloon() : $(this).showBalloon();
       shown = !shown;
    }).showBalloon({
      contents: "次の文字は原則として利用できません。/ ! “@ # $ % & ‘ ( ) = ~ | \ ^ : ; * + ? < > , ` [ ] { }<br>＠の直前には英数字のみとなります。<br>.（ドット）は2つ以上連続して利用できません。",
      html: true,
      classname: "balloon",
      position: "right",
      tipSize: 10,
      showDuration: 0,
      css: {
      opacity: "1",
      color: "#000",
      backgroundColor: "#F8F8FF",
      fontSize: "8px",
      borderRadius: "10px",
      border: "solid 1px #222"
    }
  });
});
```

rspec file

```
RSpec.describe 'Balloon', type: :feature, js: true do
  before do
    WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow_localhost => true)
  end

  ...

  scenario "balloon", focus: true do
    visit '/mypage/balloon'

    find("#my_balloon").click

    # if balloon worked, below div will display with class balloon
    expect(page).to have_selector(:css, "div.balloon")
  end
end
```

But i can not make it work on test. in debug mode it work normally

> If i stop `byebug` at line `find("#my_balloon").click` and trigger click manually next expect will pass.

anyone have idea about this.

Comment: '/mypage/baloon' <- is that the right url? Balloon is spelled differently. But then it doesn't explain why the manual trigger works :-/

Comment: @kuwantum thanks for announced me. my typing error. sorry just fixed my question

Comment: Ah, so I didn't get lucky and find the answer then haha! Have you checked the test can find #my_balloon on the page?

Comment: @kuwantum yup, did it. but, do not work. i search a lot on the internet but do not get the answer.

Comment: @hoang.vx What do you mean by "trigger click manually"? Are you saying if you run `find("#my_balloon").click` in the console, it works? If yes, then does adding a `sleep` above that line also make the test pass? Or alternatively, are you saying that you're *clicking the button manually with the mouse*?

Comment: @TomLord yeah i mean to do it in the console and it work. i am try to using the wait_util too but it go to timeout!

Comment: @TomLord Thanks, just try to sleep before click the button and it work like a champ.

Comment: @hoang.vx OK, that's a great start! Now, using `sleep` is of course a "poor man's fix". Since we now know the issue is that *something* isn't initialized fully when the code gets run, ideally you want to figure out *what's* not initialized and then *explicitly wait for it* (rather than just `sleep`ing an arbitrary period).

Comment: ...But of course, this may end up being more trouble than it's worth. If you can live with a `sleep`, and life is too short to improve the test, then just leave it as that. It's your call.

Comment: @TomLord thanks a lots.